# Getting file size of carrierwave upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, carrierwave

I am trying to get the file size of a carrierwave upload.  I am trying to do things such as:

```
<%= upload.file.size %>
```

and

```
<%= upload.file_size %>
```

and neither are working.  I also ran :methods on my upload and didn't see anything there that would lead me to the file size of the upload.  How do I get the file size of the upload?

Answer (score 13):

Here's the answer.  CarrierWave does not specifically give it to you so you have to do a nice work around:

```
number_to_human_size(object.attachment.file.size)
```

Answer (score 4):

/app/uploaders/attachment_file_uploader.rb

```
class AttachmentFileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  storage :file

  process :set_content_type
  process :store_file_attributes

  ....

  private

  def store_file_attributes
    if file && model
      model.file_name  = File.basename(file.file)
      model.file_size  = File.size(file.file)
      model.human_size = number_to_human_size(model.file_size)
    end
  end

end
```

migration:

```
class CreateAttachments < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    create_table :attachments do |t|
      t.references :attachable, polymorphic: true
      t.string     :file
      t.string     :file_name
      t.integer    :file_size
      t.string     :human_size
      t.string     :description

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately carrierwave doesn't provide method to determine filesize of your upload once it has been stored (since it doesn't know it and only way to do it is to re-access the file and check it's file size). You can go with two different scenarios here:

1. Create a helper which will retrieve the file from the storage and determine the size of it (which can be tricky and I personally won't go that way).
2. Record the size of the file once it is uploaded and store it as an attribute of your model (there is a guide [in Carrierwave wiki](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Store-the-uploaded-file-size-and-content-type) describing how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is way late, but I thought I'd add for future viewers.

Follow the link if you want to use with RMagick and MiniMagick

"If you assign the dimensions to the model (that you've mounted the uploader to) in a custom processor, that will be saved along with the image path when you upload."

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Get-image-dimensions

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base 
  process :store_dimensions

  # If you like, you can call this inside a version like this
  # instead of at the top level.
  # That will store the dimensions for this version.
  version :show do
    process :resize_to_limit => [500, 500]
    process :store_dimensions
  end

  private

  def store_dimensions
    if file && model
      model.width, model.height = `identify -format "%wx%h" #{file.path}`.split(/x/)
    end
  end
end
```